# How do I get random numbers in Elm 0.13 without a signal?

Tags: random, elm

I'm making a game where I need to draw random lines on the screen. Now it seems like Random needs a signal to work in 0.13 (and we are forced to work in 0.13). So how do I obtain those random number?

I started from the game skeleton provided at the elm-lang website and got to this:

```
type UserInput = { space : Bool, keys : [KeyCode] }
type Input = { timeDelta : Float, userInput : UserInput }

userInput : Signal UserInput
userInput = lift2 UserInput Keyboard.space Keyboard.keysDown

framesPerSecond = 30

delta : Signal Float
delta = lift (\t -> t / framesPerSecond) (Time.fps framesPerSecond)

input : Signal Input
input = Signal.sampleOn delta (Signal.lift2 Input delta userInput)

gameState : Signal GameState
gameState = Signal.foldp stepGame defaultGame input

stepGame : Input -> GameState -> GameState
stepGame i g =
  if g.state == Start then *Get random floats*
```

Now in stepGame, I want to draw random lines. The problem is that [I can only get random floats by providing a signal in 0.13](http://library.elm-lang.org/catalog/elm-lang-Elm/0.13/Random). I have the Input signal close by the step function, but when I change the header to lets say
`stepGame : Signal Input -> GameState -> GameState` it doesn't compile. So how do I get a signal in that function to get some random numbers... I can't seem to find the solution, it's driving me crazy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to do this. It really depends on whether the amount of random numbers you need is static or not.

## Static number of random numbers

Extend your `input` with random numbers from `Random.floatList`:

```
type Input = { timeDelta : Float, userInput : UserInput, randoms : [Float] }

staticNoOfFloats = 42

input : Signal Input
input = Signal.sampleOn delta (Signal.lift3 Input delta userInput (Random.floatList (always staticNoOfFloats <~ delta)))
```

## Dynamic number of random numbers

Use a community library ([also outlined in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21381278/859279)) called [generator](http://library.elm-lang.org/catalog/jcollard-generator/0.4). You can use a random seed by using `Random.range` in much the same way as outlined above. The library is a pure pseudo-random number generator based on generating a random number and a new `Generator` that will produce the next random number.

### Why not use `Random.floatList` in the dynamic case?

Usually if you need a dynamic number of random numbers that number is dependent on the current state of the program. Because that state is captured inside the `foldp`, where you're also doing your updating based on those random numbers, this makes it impossible to use a "signal function", i.e. something of type `Signal a -> Signal b`.